# Xcode: load json link in webview

Tags: iphone, xcode, json, webview

I want to load a link from my Json database in a webview. But I have no idea how I can do this.

This is a part from my json:

```
{
    "ID": "6173",
    "Name": "Heuriger Christine Haller",
    "BeschreibungApp": "Heuriger Christine Haller, 2102 Bisamberg",
    "Link": "http://heurigenapp.nocache.gugler.at/app.php?id=6173",
    "Icon": "Weintraube",
    "Latitude": "48.33284",
    "Longitude": "16.36383",
    "Altitude": "0",
    "Ort": "Bisamberg"
}
```

and I want to open the "Link" in a webview.

Answer (score 1):

Use a parser like [json-framework](https://github.com/stig/json-framework) to parse the received json. Then it will be easy for you to extract the required item from it.

The code will be something like this :

```
SBJsonParser* parser = [[[SBJsonParser alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDictionary* dict = [parser objectWithString:jsonString];
NSString* url = [dict objectForKey:@"Link"];
```

Now you can use the NSString url to  load the content in a web view.

Edit:

You can better use json serilization from ios5. Check this tut : http://www.raywenderlich.com/5492/working-with-json-in-ios-5

Comment: is it also possible without json-framework? Because i read in another article that it is much easier with json-serlialisation when i work with ios 5

Comment: oh ys! forget about that new feature. I just edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [NSJSONSecialization](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html) Class that is included in Mac OS >10.7 and iOS >5.
The code to get the link from your example would look like this:

```
NSString* jsonString = @"your json as a string";
NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];
NSString* link = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Link"];
NSURL* linkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:link];
```

Comment: perfect this is what i was searching for!

But can you also help me how i can give this out in my webview?

Comment: AFAIK you need to create a HTML file with your data, save that file to the disk and then pass the URL of the file to the webview. However creating an HTML file is independent from parsing JSON. Google gave me this tutorial for webviews but you will easily find others, too: http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2008/08/uiwebview-tutorial.html  Also if this is the answer your were looking for you should accept it :-)

Comment: NSString* jsonString = @"my json string";

NSData* jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  
NSDictionary* jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:NULL];

NSString* link = [jsonDict objectForKey:@"Link"];
    
NSURL* url = [NSURL URLWithString:link];

//URL Requst Object
 
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
 
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];

Comment: this is my code. but there must be a mistake it doesn't work.

Comment: You need to replace '@"my json string"' with your real json data in string format. Or if you get your json data in binary format you can directly use an NSData object. If you get errors, you can also print the received JSON and the generated Dictionary `NSLog(@"parsed jsonDict: %@", jsonDict)`

Comment: yes already replaced my link.
but my code didn't work i olny see a white screen

Comment: Displaying the link is independent of the json parsing. So you should check if your webView code is correct by directly passing the link (not extracting it from json) and check if your json is parsed correctly by logging the resulting dictionary. If the problem is in your webview code you should open a new question for that.